# Cannot install atom package pandoc-convert in Manjaro

Tags: atom-editor, pandoc, manjaro

When I try to install the package pandoc-convert 1.1.0 on Atom 1.14.3 using the Manjaro LXqt OS 16.11 I get the following error:

```
Installing “pandoc-convert@1.1.0” failed.Hide output…
(node:9072) DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.

pandoc-bin@0.1.2 postinstall /tmp/apm-install-dir-117127-9072-634y30.v7yhbk2o6r/node_modules/pandoc-convert/node_modules/pandoc-bin
node index.js
⧗ Downloading Pandoc (~20-50MB depending on OS). This may take a minute or so.
/tmp/apm-install-dir-117127-9072-634y30.v7yhbk2o6r
└── (empty)

npm WARN deprecated win-spawn@2.0.0: use cross-spawn or cross-spawn-async instead.
npm WARN deprecated find-file@0.1.4: Use the globby package instead
path.js:7
throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' + inspect(path));
^

TypeError: Path must be a string. Received { url: 'https://raw.github.com/toshgoodson/pandoc-bin/0.1.0/vendor/linux/x64/pandoc',
name: 'pandoc',
os: 'linux',
arch: 'x64' }
at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
at Object.basename (path.js:1355:5)
at /tmp/apm-install-dir-117127-9072-634y30.v7yhbk2o6r/node_modules/pandoc-convert/node_modules/download/index.js:35:43
at each (/tmp/apm-install-dir-117127-9072-634y30.v7yhbk2o6r/node_modules/pandoc-convert/node_modules/each-async/each-async.js:63:4)
at module.exports (/tmp/apm-install-dir-117127-9072-634y30.v7yhbk2o6r/node_modules/pandoc-convert/node_modules/download/index.js:33:5)
at /tmp/apm-install-dir-117127-9072-634y30.v7yhbk2o6r/node_modules/pandoc-convert/node_modules/bin-wrapper/index.js:108:20
at /tmp/apm-install-dir-117127-9072-634y30.v7yhbk2o6r/node_modules/pandoc-convert/node_modules/bin-wrapper/index.js:141:24
at /tmp/apm-install-dir-117127-9072-634y30.v7yhbk2o6r/node_modules/pandoc-convert/node_modules/bin-check/index.js:30:20
at /tmp/apm-install-dir-117127-9072-634y30.v7yhbk2o6r/node_modules/pandoc-convert/node_modules/executable/index.js:39:20
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:114:15)
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/apm-install-dir-117127-9072-634y30.v7yhbk2o6r/package.json'
npm WARN apm-install-dir-117127-9072-634y30.v7yhbk2o6r No description
npm WARN apm-install-dir-117127-9072-634y30.v7yhbk2o6r No repository field.
npm WARN apm-install-dir-117127-9072-634y30.v7yhbk2o6r No README data
npm WARN apm-install-dir-117127-9072-634y30.v7yhbk2o6r No license field.
npm ERR! Linux 4.8.5-2-MANJARO
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "--globalconfig" "/home/martinezce/.atom/.apm/.apmrc" "--userconfig" "/home/martinezce/.atom/.apmrc" "install" "/tmp/d-117127-9072-m6rmws.6kl2mg3nmi/package.tgz" "--runtime=electron" "--target=1.4.15" "--arch=x64" "--global-style"
npm ERR! node v7.6.0
npm ERR! npm v4.3.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! pandoc-bin@0.1.2 postinstall: node index.js
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pandoc-bin@0.1.2 postinstall script 'node index.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the pandoc-bin package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! node index.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR! npm bugs pandoc-bin
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! npm owner ls pandoc-bin
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! /home/martinezce/.atom/.apm/_logs/2017-02-27T13_55_01_959Z-debug.log
```

I can install it on a Windows machine fine, but on Manjaro it doesn't work.
Maybe, it's a package issue?

Thank you for your help.

Best Regards,

Cédric Martinez

Comment: Do you have the latest node.js and npm installed? If so, it's likely an issue with the package or a dependency not supporting your OS properly.

Comment: Yes according to pacman, I have npm version 4.3.0-1 and nodejs version 7.7.1-1 both from community